# Counting seconds until auto-log-off

Tags: bash

I've just created a teeny little script to count the seconds until I get auto-logged off.  I already solved my issue with my ssh client settings, but I'd still like any help making the bash script nicer to read, or just tips in general.

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0
while ( [ : ] )
do
  count=$(($count+1))
  n=${n:-0}
  for i in `seq 0 $n`; do echo -en '\b'; done
  n="${#count}"
  echo -n $count
  sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
count=0
while true; do
  printf "\r%d" $((++count))
  sleep 1
done
```

Your while condition is doing a lot of work just to return true: you launch a subshell, and evaluate  a test giving a 1-character string (which will [always return true](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-test)). Make it simpler and more readable by just executing the [`true`](http://man.cx/true) program.

Note that variable names inside an arithmetic expression do not require the leading dollar sign in most cases. That's quietly documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic):

> "Within an expression, shell variables may also be referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax."

`printf` is more portable than `echo`, if that's a concern for you. I also find it makes your intentions more obvious.

Instead of backing up the right number of characters, just carriage return to the first column and overwrite the previous contents.

Comment: No freaking way.  I _did_ previously know about /bin/true, I just didn't think of it.  However, I never knew bash had a ++ syntax, nor did I realize I can use variable names _without_ the dollar sign.  THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

If the answer is what you care for,

in your .bash_profile :

```
touch "~/.loggued_in"
```

in your .bash_logout:

```
date -r ~/.loggued_in ; date
```

and check if there is a timeout setup:

```
{ set ; env ; } | egrep 'TM|TIME|OUT' | sort | uniq
```

and lastly, if connecting via something like Putty (or other), they can be setup to have a "keepalive" sent regularly (usually a "nop"). In Putty, "Settings - Connection - seconds between keepalives" (0 by default : set it to, say, 50 if you get auto loggued off after 1mn)

ok, about the code itself : very nice for displaying the time in an interresting manner (sort of like a progress bar). If you prefer it in one place (and no need for an extra $n) :

```
while ( [ : ] ); do count=$(($count+1)); echo -en '\b\b\b\b'; printf "%4s" $count; sleep 1; done
```

Comment: sorry for the 3 first parts: i got used to questions on so ... I believe my answer is not at all what you need here, ie code review - wise... But your script is quite fine already. Let's see what others propose as interresting modifications

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments.  I tried to give you guys a point but it's saying I have to login (which I don't want to do right now).  It let me do the check box though.  Oh and yes I had already determined how to prevent ssh disconnects.  It did take me a long time, I should have asked on here. :-)